# How can I make this big chunk of program smaller ? Will it work?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm currently working on a Node JS/Puppeteer project which inputs characters on a registration form from a dictionary that changes with a variable. For this I made a big chunk of code:

```
        if (c1 == 1){
            "a" = dict["Chara1"]
        } else {
            if (c1 == 2) {
                "b" = dict["Chara1"]
            } else {
                if (c1 == 3){
                    "c" = dict["Chara1"]
                } else {
                    if (c1 == 4) {
                        "d" = dict["Chara1"]
                    } else {
                        if (c1 == 5){
                            "e" = dict["Chara1"]
                        } else {
                            if (c1 == 6) {
                                "f" = dict["Chara1"]
                            } else {
                                if (c1 == 7){
                                    "g" = dict["Chara1"]
                                } else {
                                    if (c1 == 8) {
                                        "h" = dict["Chara1"]
                                    } else {
                                        if (c1 == 9){
                                            "i" = dict["Chara1"]
                                        } else {
                                            if (c1 == 10) {
                                                "j" = dict["Chara1"]
                                            } else {
                                                if (c1 == 11){
                                                    "k" = dict["Chara1"]
                                                } else {
                                                    if (c1 == 12) {
                                                        "l" = dict["Chara1"]
                                                    } else {
                                                        if (c1 == 13){
                                                            "m" = dict["Chara1"]
                                                        } else {
                                                            if (c1 == 14) {
                                                                "n" = dict["Chara1"]
                                                            } else {
                                                                if (c1 == 15){
                                                                    "o" = dict["Chara1"]
                                                                } else {
                                                                    if (c1 == 16) {
                                                                        "p" = dict["Chara1"]
                                                                    } else {
                                                                        if (c1 == 17){
                                                                            "q" = dict["Chara1"]
                                                                        } else {
                                                                            if (c1 == 18) {
                                                                                "r" = dict["Chara1"]
                                                                            } else {
                                                                                if (c1 == 19){
                                                                                    "s" = dict["Chara1"]
                                                                                } else {
                                                                                    if (c1 == 20) {
                                                                                        "t" = dict["Chara1"]
                                                                                    } else {
                                                                                        if (c1 == 21){
                                                                                            "u" = dict["Chara1"]
                                                                                        } else {
                                                                                            if (c1 == 22) {
                                                                                                "v" = dict["Chara1"]
                                                                                            } else {
                                                                                                if (c1 == 23){
                                                                                                    "w" = dict["Chara1"]
                                                                                                } else {
                                                                                                    if (c1 == 24) {
                                                                                                        "x" = dict["Chara1"]
                                                                                                    } else {
                                                                                                        if (c1 == 25){
                                                                                                            "y" = dict["Chara1"]
                                                                                                        } else {
                                                                                                            if (c1 == 26) {
                                                                                                                "z" = dict["Chara1"]
                                                                                                            } else {
                                                                                                                
                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                }
                                                                                            }
                                                                                        }
                                                                                    }
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

As I'm a beginner in Node JS I've tried to search tutorials or documentation, but I didn't find/understand anything and I know that it's probably gonna end with a Node JS crash or something that doesn't work as this chunk of code will be in 8 copy. I want to know how to make it smaller.

Ps: Sorry if my English is bad, I'm not Anglophone.

Comment: That code won't work in the first place; you can't assign to a string literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** the end result you want is the `dict` object having a `Chara1` key with an array of alphabet (1-indexed), all you need is

```
const dict = {
  Chara1: [null, ..."abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"],  // alphabet, one-indexed
  Digit1: [..."0123456789"],  // digits, zero-indexed
}
```

– this uses [the `...` spread syntax](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to "paste" the string into the array.

You can then do e.g. this to get the fifth (1-indexed) letter in the alphabet:

```
> console.log(dict.Chara1[5]);
'e'
```

Comment: If I use this method, can I also have a Chara2, Chara3, etc... doing the same ?

Comment: Of course. Just add them there in the dict; see my edit.

Comment: Also, in my loop I've put a system that increment c1 and then put it to 1 to increment c2 etc... As it's the same problem (I don't know how to make it smaller, if it's possible and if it could work) I asked it here.
Here is the base block of this "system"
'''if (c1 > 25) {
            c1 = 1
            (same for c2, c3, etc...)
        } else {
            c1 += 1
        }'''

Comment: Are you maybe trying to generate all combinations of a string? Like `aaa`, `aab`, `aac`..?

Comment: Yes that's it, I want to generate all combination of a string of 8 character/digit

Comment: Then please see my answer from 11 years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8823066/51685

Comment: I tried it and it actually broke the copy of the program on wich I make test...